# Peak Over Threshold

Tags: jquery, distribution, probability

The probability of exceedence, Q is calculated using the formula

```
Q=(i-c1)/(N-C2)

Where 
     i--> rank
     N-->total no of data
     c1 & C2 are constants
```

Here rank means what? Any specific formula is there to calculate rank.
I need to calculate these formula using jquery. Is there any jquery Plugin.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is the rank of data in descending order i.e ranking of 1 for the highest data value and the lowest data value received the rank N